# How to figure out if a 25V capacitor can replace 50V in this circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, multimeter

I'm following this video [Astable 555 timer - 8-bit computer clock - part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRlSFm519Bo) where he builds this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmqnqz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I just realized that the 1000uF capacitor I have is 25V and not 50V as the one he uses in the video. I suspect that 25V will do but I don't know for sure.

I've tested the voltage where the capacitor would have been in the circuit on my multimeter and that reads 55.3mV which is much less that 25V but maybe the 555 timer can change that?

Is this a valid way to figure out the maximum voltage the circuit will apply to the capacitor?

Comment: To answer the question in your title, you figure out how much voltage can actually appear across the capacitor, add something for the capacitor tolerance in case it is at the bottom of the variance, and then add 20% safety margin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to know for certain would be to measure as you did (although you said 'where it would have been' which might suggest you had it removed).  In this case since the highest voltage source is 5V, and there is no boost converter topology present to increase the voltage (you would need an inductor to do that), the cap would never see more than 5V.  A 25V rated cap would be perfectly fine.

In general, if you rely on measurement though, be sure that you check it under all possible operating conditions.  Ideally you should understand the circuit well enough to know what potential voltages (and current) may be present at any given component.

EDIT: If you plan to take measurements (of a non-steady-state circuit such as this) to confirm your expectations of peak voltage on a cap, it's probably best to use a scope if possible, since meters won't reliably capture brief pulses or transients.

Comment: You don't need an inductor to boost the voltage.   Look up "charge pump".  But you're still right, there's no booster in this circuit.

Comment: Yes, right @Oskar, thanks for correcting me.  Charge pumps don't use inductors.  I should have remembered that since I use them quite a bit generating 5V for USB from AA batteries.

Comment: @Robin, edited my answer to include a note about using a scope over a meter if possible.

Comment: @AngeloQ: Believe me, I dream of owning a scope but I can't justify it economically right now.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, a 25 V capacitor is fine here.  Even 10 V would be fine.  The voltage on the cap can't exceed 5 V as you show the circuit.

Just because "someone on the internet" uses a particular value part doesn't mean that the value is optimized.  In this case, it was probably just the value he had handy.

On a separate topic, using a <s>666</s> 555 timer for a "computer clock" sounds like a bad idea.  These things aren't anywhere near accurate enough for keeping real time.  Unless you pay lots of money, the analog parts are ±10% at best.  For a clock, that comes out to nearly 15 minutes error per day.  To get 1 minute error per month, for example, you need 23 PPM accuracy.  That basically means using a 20 PPM crystal.  Note that 10% is 100,000 PPM, rather a lot more.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but for a computer with only 16 bytes (not kilo) of RAM the amount of instructions are very limited and if the timer should double tick once it probably does not matter?

Comment: @Robin: The number of RAM bytes has nothing to do with the amount of clock jitter the processor can tolerate.  Besides, I wasn't talking about jitter, but about long term accuracy if used for tracking real time.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. Unfortunately a classic case of jumping to conclusions. This is not a 'Real time clock', it's not even trying to be an accurate CPU clock. It's simply one component in a quite extensive project to develop a TTL logic based computer. Even a cursory look at the video would have shown this. Context means everything.

Comment: @Jack: You can't seriously expect people to watch a video to get relevant information to a question!  "CPU clock" can mean different things.  I mentioned one thing to be aware of for one of the interpretations.  Apparently it doesn't apply in this case, but it might to others who come here from searches.

Comment: @Olin. I'd expect anyone answering the question to ensure they understood the context in which 'CPU Clock' was being used. So many commenting and answering on StackExchange rip into the questions when they think the questioner has not done due diligence. It's only fair that those answering should be diligent too.

Comment: @JackCreasey: Even if it’s only used for a CPU clock the accuracy can still be important if you operate close to the maximum frequency or drive asynchronous communication interfaces like RS232.

Comment: @Michael. Again, my point was answering the question in context. The question was related to a project where there is almost zero dependency on clock rate and certainly zero dependency on accuracy, stability/drift, or even jitter.

Comment: @Jack: I really don't see what you're objecting to.  The first two paragraphs directly answer what the OP asked.  The third mentions something to watch out for that is relevant for some meanings of "computer clock", a term *that was not defined in the question*.  Again, expecting those spending their free time answering questions to watch a linked video is unrealistic and unreasonable.  The discussion about accuracy is still correct by itself, just not relevant in this particular case - apparently.  -1 if you must, but get over it already.

Comment: Olin - I appreciate you adding extra information. I've answered a lot of questions on the chemistry site and quite frequently the posters have no idea about other important issues.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: While I do appreciate the extra information my question was actually if I was measuring correctly and not just if the 25V capacitor was a valid replacement in this specific scenario. So next time I have this issue I know how to use my multimeter. Hence that is why I accepted the answer from AngeloQ. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In general just measuring the voltage across the capacitor at one point in time probably isn't the most valid way to figure out the maximum voltage it would expect, though it certainly is a start.

If you want to go the measurement route, then you must ensure the voltage at all points in time (all possible operating conditions) doesn't exceed your value. Practically this is somewhat cumbersome I think, unless you have access to an oscilloscope that can record the max voltage over some period of time and probe it with that? Even then, if you do this in the dark (not understanding the circuit) you might not be sure you put the circuit into a condition where the capacitor would expect peak voltage.

So, likely the "most valid" approach would be to gain a very firm understanding of the operation of your circuit to determine analytically if you should ever expect the capacitor voltage to exceed the supply voltage, if there is any voltage increasing circuitry present, and using empirical measurement to support your expectations.